# Not able to Dynamically Change Label text in Kivy Python

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, label, kivy, dashboard

I am trying to make a program to display a table using Kivy.
Here I have the table names as buttons, and the values are defined by labels.
Using a function, I am putting labels as per the number of rows and columns,
then I want to populate them externally using another function, it throws an Index_Error. Heres my entire code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import runTouchApp

    class TableView(GridLayout):
    Col_Names = ["Date","Vendor","Country","MOU","ASR","AOU"]
    Label_List =[]

    MyListOfElements = [['1sample1','1sample2','1sample3','1sample4','1sample5','1sample6'],
                  ['2sample1','2sample2','2sample3','2sample4','2sample5','2sample6'],
                  ['3sample1','3sample2','3sample3','3sample4','3sample5','3sample6'],
                  ['4sample1','4sample2','4sample3','4sample4','4sample5','4sample6']]

    def AddLables(self,columns, rows):
        self.LabelRow = []
        for i in range(columns):
            for j in range(rows):
                lbl = Label(size_hint_y =None, size_hint_x = None , width =30)
                self.layout.add_widget(lbl)
                self.LabelRow.append(lbl)
        self.Label_List.append(self.LabelRow)

    def AddLabel_Text(self,columns, rows):
        for i in range(columns):
            for j in range(rows):
                self.Label_List[i][j].text = self.MyListOfElements[i][j]


    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.layout  = GridLayout(cols = len(self.Col_Names), padding =5)
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(len(self.Col_Names)):
            btn = Button(text=self.Col_Names[i], size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            self.layout.add_widget(btn)
        self.AddLables(4,6)
        self.AddLabel_Text(4,6)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    Table = TableView()
    runTouchApp(Table.layout)
```

I want an alternative solution to update the Label Name just by calling a function. I know that Labels in python cannot be directly indexed, but is there any alternate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following line should have a different indententation level

```
self.Label_List.append(self.LabelRow)
```

try:

```
    for i in range(columns):
        for j in range(rows):
            lbl = Label(size_hint_y =None, size_hint_x = None , width =30)
            self.layout.add_widget(lbl)
            self.LabelRow.append(lbl)
            #lbl.text = self.MyListOfElements[i][j]
   #--->Now it's inside the first loop!
        self.Label_List.append(self.LabelRow)
```

Now you'll have enough rows so that **AddLabel_Text** won't fail

Comment: Its the AddLabel_Text function that is causing the problem. That other statement is commented out deliberately.

Comment: It's causing the problem because you didn't build-it correctly, as I stated in my answer

Comment: Ok, now theres a different problem. It displays only one row and not all of them, and doesnt display the last element in each row.